# CentOS7 How to Install Nuget Package Manager

Tags: c#, mono, devops, centos7, rpm

I'm on CentOS7, and I'm struggling to install nuget.

The usual suspect of:

```
yum install nuget
```

fails.

How to do this seemingly simple operation?

Answer (score 0):

First install needed tools:

```
yum install -y wget
```

Add the Nuget Repo:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/
```

Add a needed key:

```
rpm --import "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF"
```

Mono is needed for Nuget:

```
yum install -y mono-complete
```

Pull down Nuget RPM:

```
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/n/nuget-2.8.7-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Install Nuget RPM:

```
rpm -i nuget-2.8.7-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Clean up RPM:

```
rm -f nuget-2.8.7-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: People should avoid using Mono when .NET 6 is on the way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos Install .NET Core SDK and then `dotnet nuget` gives you the core functionalities.